# captcha img and avatar img not showing up

Tags: image, captcha

I am trying to run a rating and review software on my site. I can not get the avatar or the captcha images to show up. How do I adjust this on my server running windows IIS?

`extension=php_gd2.dll`

```
<label class="xcFormLabel" for="idRegAvatar">
  Avatar - images will be resized to 80px x 80px (100k):
</label>
<div class="xcDivClear">
</div>
<input type="file" name="avatar" id="idRegAvatar" value="" class="xcRegInputText" />
<br /><br />
<img class="xcRegCaptchaImg" src="../xcommentpro/Captcha.php?type=reg">
<br /><br />
<label class="xcFormLabel" for="idRegCaptcha">
  Enter the code above:
</label>
<br />
<input type="text" name="captcha" id="idRegCaptcha" class="xcRegInputText" />
<br /><br />
```

The following error appears:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg() in C:\www\recipes4cakes\xcommentpro\fileupload.php on line 64

Comment: Show us yr code pleaz!!!

Comment: <label class="xcFormLabel"  for="idRegAvatar">Avatar - images will be resized to 80px x 80px (100k):</label><div class="xcDivClear"></div><input type="file" name="avatar" id="idRegAvatar"  value="" class="xcRegInputText" /><br /><br />
       <img class="xcRegCaptchaImg" src="../xcommentpro/Captcha.php?type=reg"> <br /><br />
   <label class="xcFormLabel"  for="idRegCaptcha">Enter the code above:</label><br />
   <input type="text" name="captcha" id="idRegCaptcha"  class="xcRegInputText" /><br /><br />

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg() in C:\www\recipes4cakes\xcommentpro\fileupload.php on line 64

Answer (score 0):

Error comes from problem with the GD-library. You need to check for JPEG support in your phpinfo() (GD section), otherwise the imagecreatefromjpeg() function won't work.